# jquery help selecting the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have this HTML

```
<li>
    <a rel="1" href="/jobwall/job/1">
        <img src="http://lcl.moovjob.com/media/images/employers/simonainleydotinfo.jpg">
    </a>
</li>
```

and I have this javascript

```
$('ul#jobs li a').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/jobwall/job_tooltip',
        data: 'employer_id='+$(this).attr('rel'),
        success:function(html) {
            $(this).parent($(this)).addClass('added');
        }
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#wrapper').append('Leave');
});
```

On mouse enter I am wanting to add a class the li that holds the a that has the mouseenter event on it, however I cannot get it to add the class on mouseenter.

Comment: As a note, you can save a few keystrokes by using `.hover()` and including the 2 anonymous functions for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` as comma separated callbacks in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your this inside of the success event will be the window not the anchor element.
Take a ref of the anchor outside the .ajax call and use it in the success event.

```
 $('ul#jobs li a').mouseenter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().addClass('active');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/jobwall/job_tooltip',
        data: 'employer_id='+$(this).attr('rel'),
        success:function(html) {
            $this.parent().addClass('added');
        }
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#wrapper').append('Leave');
});
```

Comment: +1 For the answer, but the description is a little off. Inside `success`, jQuery sets the value of `this` to be to the `xhr` object instead of `window`. Not relevant to the solution, of course. :o)

Answer (score 2):

You have two calls to `.addClass()`. Which one are you talking about?

The first one should work.

The second one will not because the value of `this` has changed inside the `success:` callback. You can cache it in a variable and reference it inside.

```
$('ul#jobs li a').mouseenter(function(){

      // cache the parent here, because "this" will have different
      //    meaning in the callback
    var $parent = $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/jobwall/job_tooltip',
        data: 'employer_id='+$(this).attr('rel'),
        success:function(html) {

             // Inside here, "this" no longer references the DOM element
            $parent.addClass('added'); // reference the parent you cached
        }
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#wrapper').append('Leave');
});
```

Another option would be to set the `context:` property of the AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    context: this,  // set the context to the current "this" for the callback
    url: '/jobwall/job_tooltip',
    data: 'employer_id='+$(this).attr('rel'),
    success:function(html) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('added');
    }
});
```

And another option would be to [use `$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy) to retain the value of `this`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/jobwall/job_tooltip',
    data: 'employer_id='+$(this).attr('rel'),
    success: $.proxy( function(html) {      // Have $.proxy return a function 
        $(this).parent().addClass('added'); // with the proper "this"
    }, this )
});
```

Comment: @redsquare - Yeah, I was slackin'. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You're mis-calling the `parent` method.
Change it to

```
$(this).parent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('added');
```

Or just

```
$(this).parent().addClass('added');
```